# Fitting gamma distribution to data set with one zero observation

Tags: maximum-likelihood, gamma-distribution, zero-inflation

I am using maximum likelihood estimation to fit a gamma distribution to shelf life data. Specifically, the data I have is the time (in days) between the day a product was sold and the day the first product of that type was sold. As a result, one of the observations in my data set is zero (the first product was sold 0 days after the day the first product was sold). This produces a problem for mle, since it involves taking the log of the observations and log(0) is undefined. In my R-script I simply added a small positive value to the data to get around this problem. I'm wondering if there is a better or more standard way to deal with this problem. Thank you!

Comment: If the model is truly Gamma, there is a zero probability to observe $x=0$. If the data is made of integers, a Gamma model is not appropriate.

Comment: You will have to modify your gamma assumption in some way. You did it by introducing a shift; another way would be to have a zero-inflated gamma. A third might be to use a Tweedie model (of which the gamma is a special case), but with $p$ parameter smaller than 2. There are many possible choices.